# How to implement 360' show case on ios?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, html

Ah ... where to start ,Before I learn the iphone app develop

I found a very interesting app : [The Elements](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=At5zvd4lgSo)

You can see every object is rotatable like 3D

But it is by take many photos from every angle form objects

How to implement it ??(via Scroll view ???)

And I found Apple's new [HTML5 sample](http://www.apple.com/html5/showcase/threesixty/)

Looks like the HTML version is not smooth as the app version

Maybe it just because of the photos too less ...

So , my question is what if I have a series of pictures , how to change the picture when finger swipe the view ???And the swipe speed also effect the rotate speed.

Thanks for any reply or answers : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can look into [FVImageSequence](https://github.com/jaunce/FVImageSequenceDemo), However you may need to modify the code to auto-rotate the complete sequence.

A link to original post is [here](http://www.fvalente.org/blog/2011/12/19/fvimagesequence-for-mac-os-xios/)

The Elements app as described in your original question is just a sequence of photos that were taken on each degree by a professional Photographer.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

i think it has nothing to do with photos. Most likely its normal 3D rendering.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHiEqf5wb3g
around 7:30 , they say they use photo .
But still thanks your reply

Answer (score 0):

[Nineveh GL](http://nineveh.gl/) 3D Engine allow you to import 3D objects models(like `.obj` models that you can create with some application like [Google SketchUP](http://sketchup.google.com/)) easily in your iPhone app, you can find some tutorials [here](http://nineveh.gl/docs/tutorials/). And as @GameBit said, i don't think that by changing images when the user scrolls is the best approach.

Comment: Your answer is very close , But it is 3D model,I find some sample source , maybe I need to check it.
http://lukedurrant.com/2011/08/apples-360-rotating-ipod-html-5-source-code-download/